# column headers formation difference between csv and txt

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am processing a text file and found a strange issue between outputing the dataframe to .csv and .txt
my code:

```
with open('text1', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith('"***'):
                titles.extend( [line, 'XXX'] )
            else:
                for i, j in re.findall(r'(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', line):
                    pairs_.setdefault(i, []).extend([i, j])

    df = pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values(), columns = titles)
    df.to_csv('text2.csv', index = None)
    df.to_csv('text2.txt', index = None)
    
    file.close()
```

if I output the df to csv it looks like this as expected:
[image]

however if I output the df to txt it looks like this instead, the column headers are in weird formation:

```
"""*** Golden value for Channel[0] , CE[0] ***"",,,,,,,,,
",XXX,"""*** Golden value for Channel[1] , CE[0] ***"",,,,,,,,,
",XXX,"""*** Golden value for Channel[2] , CE[0] ***"",,,,,,,,,
",XXX,"""*** Golden value for Channel[3] , CE[0] ***"",,,,,,,,,
",XXX,"""*** Golden value for Channel[0] , CE[1] ***"",,,,,,,,,
",XXX,"""*** Golden value for Channel[1] , CE[1] ***"",,,,,,,,,
",XXX,"""*** Golden value for Channel[2] , CE[1] ***"",,,,,,,,,
",XXX,"""*** Golden value for Channel[3] , CE[1] ***"",,,,,,,,,
",XXX
Layer_00,3.59,Layer_00......
Layer_01,3.50,Layer_01......
```

this hurt me because I need to append multiple csv together by columns afterwards.
it always tells me the 'Wrong number of columns'
how I should do to fix this problem so the txt be normal like csv?

Comment: You have newlines in your header titles, so in the txt files they are kept, that dangerous. Look first box in the CSV, you have the commas, the new lines

Comment: Try to use a semicolon ; as the seperator: sep: str=';'.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a few rows from `text1`, we could then run your script